# How to write a loop that looks for a condition in two columns then adds the value in the third of a data frame?

Tags: r, genetics

[Table showing correct format of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am3U3.jpg)I have a data frame with four columns, and I need to find a way to sum the values in the third column. Only if the numbers in the first two columns are different. The only way I can think of is to maybe do an `If` loop? Is that something can be done or is there a better way?

```
Genotype summary`
   Dnov1a Dnov1b Freq rel_geno_freq
1     220    220    1   0.003367003
7     220    224    4   0.013468013
8     224    224    8   0.026936027
13    220    228   14   0.047138047
```

This is a portion of the data as an example, I need to sum the third column `Freq` for rows 7 and 13 because they are different.

Comment: Not very clear on the expected output. Can you share what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
data$new = data$Dnov1a!=data$Dnov1b
data
  Dnov1a Dnov1b  Freq rel_geno_freq new  
   <int>  <int> <int>         <dbl> <lgl>
1    220    220     1       0.00337 TRUE 
2    220    224     4       0.0135  FALSE
3    224    224     8       0.0269  TRUE 
4    220    228    14       0.0471  FALSE

sum(data$Freq[data$new])

28
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Something along this line, yes. Although, I made a mistake in my post. I mean for the ones that are different.

Comment: just changed `==` for `!=`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` way of doing it:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
   ~Dnov1a, ~Dnov1b, ~Freq, ~rel_geno_freq,
     220,    220,    1,   0.003367003,
     220,    224,    4,   0.013468013,
     224,    224,    8,   0.026936027,
     220,    228,   14,   0.047138047)

data %>%
 mutate(filter_column = if_else(Dnov1a != Dnov1b, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
 filter(filter_column == TRUE) %>%
 summarise(Total = sum(Freq))


# A tibble: 1 x 1
  Total
  <dbl>
1    18
```